# How to echo message at telegram /start?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'd like to set up a authentication through telegram using it's [deep linking](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking) api.

In order to authenticate, in my app I ask users to click on a link like:

```
https://telegram.me/myloginbot?start=somesecretkey
```

If I understand the docs correctly, I should expect the bot to echo back `somesecretky` to my server.

Now, this step of the docs is unclear to me:

> 6. Configure the webhook processor to query Memcached with the parameter that is passed in incoming messages beginning with /start

If I understand correctly, I need to configure `myloginbot` so that when the user clicks start button on the bot's page, the bot echos back to my server a url containing  `somesecretkey` and some user info. But I don't know how to do so.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212577/5779769) answer, it is suggested that:

> 6. Let the bot retrieve the username by querying the database or key-value storage for unique_code.

But I don't know how can I make the bot query the (presumably remote) database.

So really appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 9):

My understanding to deep linking is this:

1. You have a database of users. Each user has an ID. Suppose you want your Telegram bot to communicate with user `123`. But you don't know his Telegram `chat_id` (which the bot needs in order to send messages to him). How do you "entice" him to talk to the bot, thus revealing his `chat_id`? You put a link on a web page.
2. But the link has to be "personalized". You want each user to press on a slightly different link, in order to distinguish them. One way to do that is to embed user ID in the link. However, user IDs are *not* something you want to expose, so you generate a (temporary) **key** associated with each user ID, and **embed that key in the link**. For example, user `123` has the key `abcde`. His personalized link will be:

   ```
   https://telegram.me/myloginbot?start=abcde
   ```
3. Someone clicks on the link, and is led to a conversation with your bot. At the same time (or when he presses the START button), your bot will receive a message:

   ```
   /start abcde
   ```
4. On receiving that message, the bot sees that `abcde` is associated with user `123`. Telegram `chat_id` can also be extracted from the message. Now, the bot knows user `123`'s `chat_id`, and can send him messages afterwards.

To experiment with deep linking, you need a bot that can handle `/start` messages, supported by a "datastore" that remembers the key-ID associations. When Telegram docs say "memcache", they just mean something that stores the key-ID associations. For an experiment, it may be as simple as a dictionary, or an associative array. In real life, it may be Memcached (the memory caching software), or a database table.

If you use Python, I recommend taking a look at **[telepot](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot)**, a Python framework for Telegram Bot API. It does not do deep linking per se, but it does help you in receiving messages for a bot, and other bot operations in general. I also have an **[example](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot#examples-deep-linking)** there demonstrating how to output a personalized link, set up a webhook, and parse the incoming `/start` command with the key.

Comment: Thanks for your informative explanation Nick. Actually my difficulty is at step 4 when `the bot sees that abcde is associated with user 123`. I assume this process should happen on my server right? My core problem is to get back the abcde from telegram bot into my server so that I can extract chat_id from it. btw, I'm using django so prefer to do that in pure python and not rely on external libraries.

Comment: I have just tested deep linking, confirming my understanding is correct (and edited the answer above accordingly). I have also added an example there. Please visit the link mentioned above.

Comment: To receive the `/start` message, you have to set up a webhook by calling [the `setWebhook` method](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) on Bot API.

Comment: Would you please give me an example on how to use setwebhook for this purpose?

Comment: Well, an example of how to `setWebhook` is in the example link I have given above (last paragraph of my answer). Just follow the link, look at my code, and look for `setWebhook` there. If, as you have mentioned, you don't want to rely on any external library, then you'll have to learn about Telegram Bot API and programmatically make an HTTP request to it. To make HTTP requests from Python, you may use the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package.

Comment: Nick, I tried the `Webhook + Flask + Deep linking` code but ti does not post `ghijk` on telegram channel, when I click `start` button. Nor does it seem to returen the value to the bot. It is not surprising because I don't see any ssl key/cert being set. I guess your code need some modification. Really appreciate a complete working example.

Comment: The deep linking examples use webhook, and if you read the webhook [documentations](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot#webhook-interface) carefully, I explicitly state that "you will have to set up the webhook URL, SSL certificate, and web server on your own". So you are correct, there is no SSL cert included in the examples. If I am not mistaken, your above comments suggest that you already have a domain name and a web server set up. It is not too big a step to set up your own SSL certificate, right?

Comment: One more hint: to run the deep-linking example, you will have to supply the webhook URL, which is: <whatever-your-base-url>/abc

Comment: You said you are using Django. I don't see why you cannot mix Django and telepot. To set up the webhook URL, you only need two lines of Python: `bot = telepot.Bot('TOKEN')` and `bot.setWebhook('URL')`. If you are lazy, you may even execute these two lines in the Python interpreter, no script needed. Then, remember to modify your `urls.py` to route the webhook URL to the correct view.